# How can I validate so that an input is only numbers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For instance in this program I have used `try` and `except` to attempt to validate it, but it doesn't work; any ideas? I want to make sure the input is not a string.

```
userGuess = int(input("%s %s %s = ?\n" % (num1, op, num2)))
try:
    validation = int(userGuess)
except ValueError:
    print("You have not entered a number!")
```

Comment: put user guess in the try ... delete the validation line ... put it all in a while Loop

Comment: how you say it doesn't work ? what you expect it do ?

Comment: why not use `isdigit()`

Comment: @Beginner `try`/`except` is the Pythonic way of doing it. For a simple `int` you have alternatives, but try substituting a `float` for example.

Comment: @Beginner: what if the string corresponds to a negative number, like `"-3"`?

Answer (score 0):

Now it should work

You were getting the exception before the try, as you were already trying to convert hte input into an int.

```
userGuess = input("%s %s %s = ?\n" % (num1, op, num2))
try:
    validation = int(userGuess)
except ValueError:
    print("You have not entered a number!")
```

But the common practice is more like this:

```
try:
    userGuess = int(input('%s %s %s = ?\n' % (num1, op, num2)))
except ValueError:
    raise Exception('You have not entered a number!')
```

Comment: I don't understand your common practice example.  There's no need to import `Exception`, and since `input` returns a string, I'm not sure what could trigger the `ValueError`.

Comment: Let me try again.  Your `from exceptions import Exception` line doesn't do anything.  Your original code lacked the `int`, and so there was no way it could raise an exception, which is what I was puzzled by.  And it's pretty likely that the OP is using Python 3 because that's how the OP tagged the question.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you, and it's certainly not correct that `from exceptions import Exception` is common practice.

Comment: I will try one more time: `Exception` is *automatically imported*.  Start up a new interpreter, and type `Exception`.  You don't get a `NameError`.  *There is no need to import Exception*.

Comment: you can skip the 'raise exception' with a print and it works

Comment: Of course it works, BUT the program would still continue and try to use the userGuess variable somewhere after, and it would create some exceptions.  For a basic cli program, fine, but never for a real software. Exception must be always caught or raised.

Comment: okay obviously I'm new to python so thanks for informing me